# Meteor how to create global event?

Tags: meteor

How can I create a event which will run on any page?

When creating a helper on the main layout template it doesn't work.

```
Template.layout.events
  'click': ->
    console.log "you clicked on the site"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `Template.body.events` instead of `Template.layout.events` to create events for any template that will apply on anything in `<body>`

Docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_body

Comment: For any readers, note that `Template.layout.events` worked for me while `Template.body.events` did not, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 6):

you need a special package to create a global event.

install

```
meteor add gwendall:body-events
```

and you can use the events from `Template.body.events` in every template

example

```
Template.body.events({
   'click .myClass':function(){
       alert("BODY EVENT");
   }
});
```

or if you like the new syntax

```
Template.body.events({
   'click .myClass'(){
       alert("BODY EVENT");
   }
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that the above package is only required if using Iron-Router, since it 'breaks' or overrides Meteor's default rendering to the `<body>` element.

Comment: Confirmed this is the same case with Flow-Router.

Answer (score 2):

Neither answer currently is 'wrong' per se, they just work in different situations:

Event maps, `Template.body.events({})`, on Template.body [do not get applied to elements added to the body via Blaze.render](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2024), Iron-Router, Flow-Router jQuery, or the DOM API, or to the body element itself. If you are using the above you will need to add the package `body-events` to be able to utilise the event map on body using the command below:

`meteor add gwendall:body-events`

If you are not using any of the template rendering packages above then you can directly add to the body event map using the code below:

```
Template.body.events({
  'click': function () {
    alert("clicked on the page. oh yeah!");
  }
});
```

nb. it seems the latest version of Blaze [allows directly adding event maps to body](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-body)